# About for loop for lists have duplicate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to create a `for` loop but I am getting some unwantted output:

Example of my loop:

```
input1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
input2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in range(0,4,1)
    for j in range(0,5,1)
    output = input1[i] + "-" + input2[j]
    print(output)
```

After debug will have some results as below:

```
a - a
b - b
c - c
d - d
```

I do not want them, because it will equal to zero.

Can someone suggest me what to do with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont want them, because it will equal to zero". Also, this isn't  valid code. Please post the actual code.

Comment: don't you know how to use `if` ? with `if` you can print only some of pairs.

Comment: Hi, i just want after LOOP, i will have a-b a-c a-d a-e. I dont want a-a.

Comment: then use `if` to compare `input1[i]` with `input2[j]` and skip pair `a`,`a`

Comment: @furas may you describe more details? Thanks!

Comment: don't you know how to use `if`?  it is basis knowledge.

Comment: `if input1[i] != input2[j]: print(input1[i] + "-" + input2[j])`

Comment: @furas yes, Thank you so much ^^! i will try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only print an output if `input1[i]` and `input1[i]` are unequal:

```
input1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
input2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in range(len(input1)):
    for j in range(len(input2)):
        if input1[i] != input2[j]:
            output = input1[i] + "-" + input2[j]
            print(output)
```

Notice that `range(1,4,1)` and `range(1,5,1)` are incorrect, since the index of a list starts at 0 not 1. Use `range(list)` to make sure all elements in the list are iterated over.

Since you're only reading from the two lists, you can use the `for element in list` syntax, which iterates over the elements of a list and is a lot cleaner:

```
input1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
input2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in input1:
    for j in input2:
        if i != j:
            output = i + "-" + j
            print(output)
```

Output:

```
a-b
a-c
a-d
a-e
b-a
b-c
b-d
b-e
c-a
c-b
c-d
c-e
d-a
d-b
d-c
d-e
```

Comment: you could show how to use `for i in input1:` instead of `for i in range(len(input1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample code to exclude same elements:

```
input1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
input2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in range(1,4,1)
    for j in range(1,5,1)
       if input1[i] != input[j]
          output = input1[i] + "-" + input2[j]
          print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` to compare `input1[i]` with `input2[j]` and skip some pairs

```
if input1[i] != input2[j]: 
    print(input1[i] + "-" + input2[j])
```

Your code does works so I changed it.

I use `for i in input1` instead of `for i in range(1,4,1)` to make it more readable

```
input1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
input2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for i in input1:
    for j in input2:
        if i != j:
            print(i + "-" + j)
```